# Questions about the process of feature selection through feature importance

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, shapley-value

'Shap feature importance' was obtained through xgboost, and variables with the lowest feature importance were removed one by one from 50 variables until only 1 variable remained.

As a result of monitoring performance based on auc, we were able to see that performance continued to decrease from when there were 5 variables remaining. And when 10 cross validation was performed, the gap with the auc value of the train set was also drastically reduced.

So, when the same method was used using lgbm and randomforest, performance continued to decrease from when there were 5 variables remaining.

I wonder what this means. Is it okay to interpret this as having 5 very important variables remaining?

If these five variables are so important that the auc value of the model gradually decreases when these five are removed, does this mean that there are still important variables left? Or is it a result of the small number of features compared to the number of data?

The number of data is 10,000.

Comment: Before any quantitative/substantial answer can be given, you need to clarify what "important variable" means to you.

Answer (score 2):

When you evaluate feature elimination strategies such as "remove features by importance until there are X features left" through cross-validation, X is a hyper-parameter of the training process. X is simply the hyper-parameter value that gives the best performance on the cross-validation set in terms of the metric you have chosen. It is likely that with much more data, the value of "optimal" X would be higher (less risk of overfitting), and with less data, the "optimal" value of X would likely be lower. This statement also assumes that you "appropriately" jointly optimized X together with all other hyper-parameters (e.g. number of iterations, tree depth, how much data to have in each leaf node, what proportion of the features or data to sub-sample for each tree, and so on), because otherwise it might just be that "with other hyperparameters set to the following values, X is the optimal choice, but something else might be better if only we optimized the other hyper-parameters for that value of X". It might even turn out that you can get approximately the same cross-validated performance for different values of X as long as some other hyper-parameters change appropriately.

Does that mean that there are only X truly important variables? Some are likely more important than others. E.g. going to X=4 might only very slightly reduce cross-validated performance, and if that translates to a test set, you could argue that having 5 variables improves performance, but not by all that much. There are likely also additional variables being omitted that have at least some importance (every real process is pretty complex and you likely wouldn't have provided the features to the model if it were completely obvious that they cannot matter), but you don't have enough data (or not enough data in the right part of the distribution) to know. In fact, you are not necessarily selecting the same 5 variables on all cross-validation folds (after all, X=5 is just a particular hyper-parameter choice that says to select 5 variables, but the CV splits might turn out by chance so that different ones get selected), so you're likely not stably selecting the same variables and what they do on each CV split (perhaps explorable through their SHAP explanations) may vary, too.

The level of evidence (CV score improves at least a little) may also not be that strong with respect to X=4 vs. 5 vs. 6 vs. 3 vs. etc., so X=5 just happens to produce the best CV-score. I guess you could look at a confidence interval for X=5 vs. 4 vs. 6 to see how strong the evidence is, but that's not terribly robust/compelling because the point estimates & CIs will be biased, because you're evaluating these values of X (and the other hyperparameters you jointly optimized) on the same data you're evaluating them on. So, it's rather that when you look at the CI as if they were from completely new independent evaluations and the story wouldn't even be clear if you had done that, then it's even less clear when you've got this additional data-driven selection of the question.

That the same number of features is a good hyper-parameter choice for XGBoost and LightGBM is not at all surprising, because they are extremely similar. Random Forrest is a little bit different (instead of building new trees on the residuals of the previous ones, you build independent ones and average), but they are all tree-based algorithms so likely benefit from the same types of features and likely giving more correlated predictions than predictions from very different models would (see e.g. here Figure 5 in [this paper](https://dx.doi.org/10.1002/pst.2329) for an illustration of that). In contrast, a very different model e.g. neural network for tabular data, SVM with RBF kernel, an elastic-net regularized linear model with splines etc. might use different features/different numbers of features.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better or maybe even necessary to have a clear definition of what "variable importance" means in this particular case?

Comment: Feature importance obtained through shape values

Comment: I think it’s Shap importance measures that don’t work correctly when there are collinearities amount predictors.  I hope someone can check that.  To the original question, it’s doubtful that feature selection will be reliable if the confidence intervals on the individual importance measures are wide.  I think you’ll be shocked how wide they are, i.e., how little information is really contained in the data for judging relative importance of predictors.

Comment: @Björn Thank you for answer. As a result of cv, I removed variables with low feature importance of shap one by one. So how about bootstrapping it here and providing the 95% CI for the AUC to see if there is a difference between the two models when X=5 and when X=4?

Comment: The results for auc of cv are used to evaluate the generalization of the model. And how about using bootstrap's auc to get the 95% CI and use it to test whether there is a difference between the two models when X=5 and when X=4? The AUCs of the two methods are obviously different, but that's okay, right?

Comment: I know I can't choose the best X this way. My interest is not in best, but in decent performance when X = a. In other words, I want to show that it has become generalized. Is there no way?